# Converting Canadian census geocode to postal code?

Tags: geocoding, census, canada

I am looking to convert the geocode on the 2011 Canadian Census data file to postal code for free. The geocode looks like the following - 0010002.00.

I understand that Canada Post sells a PCCF file that will accomplish this.

geocoder.ca has file that will convert from long and lat to postal code but I can't see how to convert using the geocode in the census file.

Apologies if this is answered elsewhere in this forum, but I didn't see it on a search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the geocode you have referenced is a Census Tract code.  If that is the case you can not easily translate this to a postal code because a postal code, in general, will be much smaller than a Census Tract, as well as most other levels of Canadian Census geography in fact.

Converting from Census to Postal geography is an extremely complex, and messy problem to solve.  The two types of geography are generally incompatible because they have been developed for two very different purposes.  In most cases they do not overlap cleanly so you get a spatial many to many relationship that can not be resolved simply, or easily.  This is why Canada Post can still sell the PCCF, they put a great deal of effort in matching up the two geographic frameworks.